# How to find the list of columns that contain one or more null values in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to the SQL word and came across a problem where I have an IMDb schema with various tables. My query is how do I list all the columns in movie table which have one or more null values.

```
Movie:
- ID
- Title
- Year
- Date_published
- Duration
- Country
- Worldwide_gross_income
- Languages
- Production_company
```

Columns containing null values are Languages, Country and Production_company and my query is expected to return this list.

Comment: There are multiple columns that have null values and I need all of them in the output.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is use `IS NULL` and `OR` as follows:

```
Select * 
   From t
  Where Languages is null or country is null
     Or Production_company is null;
```

Or another way is to use `greatest` or `least` function as they return `null` if any of the argument is `null` as follows:

```
Select * 
   From t
  Where greatest(Languages, country, Production_company) is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what you want your result to look like. If you only want to know the columns which contain nulls you could use the fact that count ignores nulls for example

```
drop table if exists t;

create table t(data date,banca varchar(10),locale varchar(10));

insert into t values
('2021-01-01',null,'ne.ma'),('2021-01-01','credem','nevada'),('2021-01-01','crv','black')
;
select case when count(distinct banca) = count(*) then 'n/a' else 'contains nulls' end banca,
         case when count(distinct locale) = count(*) then 'n/a' else 'contains nulls' end locale
from t;

+----------------+--------+
| banca          | locale |
+----------------+--------+
| contains nulls | n/a    |
+----------------+--------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```